# Log4j2 throws org.jruby.exceptions.RaiseException: (NameError) ArrayJavaProxy is already defined

Tags: testng, log4j2

In my tests I specified a test log4j2 configuration.
It works like a charm unless I add `status="trace"` to the `<Configuration>`.
And when I do add it, I get:

```
org.testng.TestNGException: 
Cannot instantiate class api.test.test.LoggingInterceptorTest
    at org.testng.internal.ObjectFactoryImpl.newInstance(ObjectFactoryImpl.java:38)
    at org.testng.internal.ClassHelper.createInstance1(ClassHelper.java:387)
    at org.testng.internal.ClassHelper.createInstance(ClassHelper.java:299)
    at org.testng.internal.ClassImpl.getDefaultInstance(ClassImpl.java:115)
    at org.testng.internal.ClassImpl.getInstances(ClassImpl.java:200)
    at org.testng.internal.TestNGClassFinder.<init>(TestNGClassFinder.java:120)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.initMethods(TestRunner.java:409)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.init(TestRunner.java:235)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.init(TestRunner.java:205)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.<init>(TestRunner.java:153)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner$DefaultTestRunnerFactory.newTestRunner(SuiteRunner.java:536)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.init(SuiteRunner.java:159)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.<init>(SuiteRunner.java:113)
    at org.testng.TestNG.createSuiteRunner(TestNG.java:1299)
    at org.testng.TestNG.createSuiteRunners(TestNG.java:1286)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1140)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1057)
    at org.testng.IDEARemoteTestNG.run(IDEARemoteTestNG.java:72)
    at org.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter.main(RemoteTestNGStarter.java:127)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at org.testng.internal.ObjectFactoryImpl.newInstance(ObjectFactoryImpl.java:29)
    ... 18 more
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at api.test.test.LoggingInterceptorTest.<init>(LoggingInterceptorTest.java:18)
    ... 23 more
Caused by: org.jruby.exceptions.RaiseException: (NameError) ArrayJavaProxy is already defined
```

What the hell is this?

**UPDATE**

As requested, adding a test class and a log config:

```
public class LoggingInterceptorTest {

private static final String HTTP_METHOD = "http.method";
private static final String HTTP_QUERY_PARAMS = "http.query.params";
private static final String CONTENT_TYPE = "content-type";
private LoggingInterceptor interceptor = new LoggingInterceptor();

@Mock
private MuleEvent event;

@Mock
MuleMessage muleMessage;

@Spy
private RuntimeException messageException;

@BeforeMethod
void init() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    when(event.getMessage()).thenReturn(muleMessage);
}

@Test
public void testBeforeWhenSuccess() throws Exception {
    when(muleMessage.getInboundProperty(HTTP_QUERY_PARAMS)).thenReturn(new HashMap<>());
    interceptor.before(event);
    verify(event).getMessageSourceURI();
    verify(muleMessage).getInboundProperty(HTTP_METHOD);
    verify(muleMessage).getInboundProperty(HTTP_QUERY_PARAMS);
    verify(muleMessage).getInboundProperty(CONTENT_TYPE);
    verify(muleMessage).getPayloadAsString();
}

@Test
public void testLastWhenSuccess() throws Exception {
    interceptor.last(event, null, 0, false);
    verify(event).getMessageSourceURI();
    verify(muleMessage).getPayloadAsString();
}

@Test
public void testBeforeWhenFail() throws Exception {
    when(event.getMessageSourceURI()).thenThrow(messageException);
    interceptor.before(event);
    verify(messageException, atLeastOnce()).getMessage();
}

@Test
public void testLastWhenFail() throws Exception {
    when(event.getMessageSourceURI()).thenThrow(messageException);
    interceptor.last(event, null, 0, false);
    verify(messageException, atLeastOnce()).getMessage();
}

@Test
public void testLastWithNoEvent() throws Exception {
    MuleEvent outputEvent = interceptor.last(null, null, 0, false);
    Assert.assertNull(outputEvent);
}

}
```

And my logging config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="trace">
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%-5p %d [%t] %c: %m%n"/>
        </Console>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="INFO">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Comment: What is the "LoggingInterceptorTest.java:18" line? Could you share your project, or at least, the log4j configuration and the LoggingInterceptorTest class?

Comment: @juherr Edited my question. It that test I have a very simple verification of a mule-based interceptor. I pasted an entire test class, but the behavior is reproducible even with a simple method, so the tests themselves are irrelevant, the exception is thrown on init stage.